# MySQL Using Group by With Two Connected Table - Simple

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, group-by

I can't seem to get this simple piece of code working, could someone quickly help me out with it?

[image: enter image description here[My Code and The Question[![][1]]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need an aggregate expression to compute the count of facilities per cottage.

It would also be a good idea to add the `cottage_id` to the `group by` clause, in case two cottages have the same name.

Finally, you should be using modern, explicit joins (with the `on` keyword) instead of old-school, implicit joins (this does not change the results of your query but it's a good SQL coding practice).

```
select c.cottage_name, count(*) count_of_facilities
from cottage c
inner join cottage_facility cf on cf.cottage_id = c.cottage_id
group by c.cottage_id, c.cottage_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) the number of facilities associated with each `Cottage`:

```
SELECT c.Cottage_Name, COUNT(cf.Facility_ID) AS Num_Facilities
FROM Cottage c
LEFT JOIN Cottage_Facility cf ON cf.Cottage_ID = c.Cottage_ID
GROUP BY c.Cottage_Name
```

Note that you should use a `LEFT JOIN` so that you get a 0 count for any cottages that don't have any facilities.